# Transform first uppercase letter to lowercase in string

Tags: c++, string

I'm looking for a more elegant way to find the position of first uppercase letter from string than the code below:

```
size_t getFirstUppercasePosition(const string &str)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(str[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return string::npos;    
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using `find` or `find_if`?

---

ADDED:

I'm trying to convert the first uppercase letter to lowercase letter and then erase the previous part from string.

For example, `howAreYouToday` -> `areYouToday`

ADDED2:

```
const auto it = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](auto c)
                                     {return std::isupper(c);});
*it = tolower(*it);
str = str.substr(std::distance(str.begin(), it));
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: `auto it = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](auto c) { return std::isupper(c); })`

Comment: `std::find_if` would return `iterator`, not `size_t`, Do you really need index? if yes you have to translate it, with special handling for `string::npos`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Please see my added part. Don't I need to know the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda with `find_if` if you have access to C++11 and above:

```
auto itr = std::find_if(str.begin(), std.end(), [] (char chr) { return std::isupper(chr); });
if(itr != str.end())
// use itr..
```

You can then use `std::distance` if you really want the index.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please see my added part? Is it possible to do what I want without using `std::distance`?

Comment: @ZackLee That'd be the way to do it since substr only accepts an index. You could do it yourself by looping from `begin()` to `itr` but this is cleaner.